# Previous declaration of CalculateInventoryColumnWidths not marked with the 'overload' directive

Tags: delphi

I'm getting the above error in the following unit (Delphi Alexandria) along with an "Unsatisfied forward or external declaration of 'CalculateInventoryColumnWidths'" error:

```
unit InventoryListing;

interface

uses
  Classes, FireDac.Comp.Client, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.frxClass,
  AppGlobals;

procedure CalculateInventoryColumnWidths(var ColWidths: TColWidthsArray;
          var TopTitles, MiddleTitles, BottomTitles: TStringList);

implementation

uses
  SysUtils, StrUtils, System.Variants, System.UITypes,
  Globals, Data;

type
  TColWidthsArray = array of single;

var
  fInventorySQL: string;

procedure CalculateInventoryColumnWidths(var ColWidths: TColWidthsArray;
          var TopTitles, MiddleTitles, BottomTitles: TStringList);
begin
  {implementation code}
end;

End.
```

I've searched the whole project for this procedure name and only found one instance that is the actual call to this procedure.  I've tried removing the original unit from the project (that had all the details of the procedure) and created a brand new unit (above) to test with and still got the above errors.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here, but can't for the life of me figure it out.  Can someone please help me see where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The interface declaration references `TColWidthsArray`, which is probably declared in *AppGlobals*, but the implementation references the local declaration of `TColWidthsArray` given a few lines above. So both reference different types and thus don't match.

Comment: Thank you so much.  That was it.  I was misled by the error message and didn't even think of the other classes.